# Want to select only uppercase text in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

For example, for this XML,

```
<h1 item="name">HIDE and SEEK</h1>
```

I want the output to be

```
HIDE SEEK
```

Is it possible?

Comment: What version of XPath do you use? What about characters that are not letters, e.g. numbers, punctuation etc?

Comment: Using Xpath 1.0. They are only letters/numbers, no special char. 
@MathiasMüller

Comment: Fine, I have edited your question to include this information. And since I'm writing anyway, please take care of some of your past questions - some of them have answers that you should accept.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Will  accept other answers. @MathiasMüller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we do not know which version you use, the following XPath expression is valid both with XPath 1.0 and 2.0

```
normalize-space(translate(//h1,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',''))
```

In XPath 2.0 the solution could have been slightly more elegant.

Note that this does only affect lowercase letters, but not numbers, punctuation or any other character. Several whitespaces are normalized to a single space.

**An XSLT 1.0 stylesheet for illustration**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(translate(//h1,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',''))"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Input**

```
<h1 item="name">HIDE and SEEK</h1>
```

**Output**

```
HIDE SEEK
```